# Custom ads links and seo

Tags: seo

I would like to display my own ads on my website, so I'm writing plugin to do that. But I wonder how better handle links to not lose page rank. Ads inserted via javascript. Is it okay to have just `<a href=""` links or better to hide links in `onclick="openLink()"`, or may be there are other options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply mark them as nofollow. That way, the spiders know that you're not passing any of your SEO mojo to the destination. It's a simple attribute in the  tag.

```
<a href="targeturlhere" rel="nofollow">
```

That being said, Google also have one specifically for links which are adverts.

```
<a href="targeturlhere" rel="sponsored">
```

Here's Google's own instructions on this.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en

The link from that page goes to Google's explanation of its view of *buying* pagerank and how to avoid the appearance of this. So by using either `nofollow` or `sponsored` is not only beneficial to you, it's best practice too.